# Error: Unable to resolve service for type 'System.Fabric.StatelessServiceContext' while attempting to activate StartUp

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-6.0

On my .net 6, I have the following:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
         ServiceRuntime.RegisterServiceAsync(
                    "MyService",
                    context => new RandomGenerator(
                        CreateHostAsync, context));
            ServiceEventSource.Current.ServiceTypeRegistered(
                Environment.ProcessId,
                typeof(RandomGenerator).Name);
    }
```

See below:

```
 static async Task<IHost> CreateHostAsync(StatelessServiceContext context)
            {
                await Task.CompletedTask;
                Logger _logger = NLog.LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
                return Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()
                    .UseServiceProviderFactory(new AutofacServiceProviderFactory())
                    //.ConfigureServices(new StatelessServiceContext())
                    
                   .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webHostBuilder => {
                       webHostBuilder
                        .ConfigureServices(
                                    services => services
                                        .AddSingleton(context))
                         .UseStartup<StartUp>();
                   })
                    ...
              }
```

Then, I have the Startup class below:

```
public class StartUp
 {
        private StatelessServiceContext _context;
        private KeyedCollection<string, ConfigurationProperty> _databaseParameters;
        public StartUp(StatelessServiceContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
            var configurationPackage = _context.CodePackageActivationContext.GetConfigurationPackageObject("Config");

            _databaseParameters = configurationPackage.Settings.Sections["MyAppDBDatabase"].Parameters;


        }
        

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
           ...
        }

        public void ConfigureContainer(ContainerBuilder builder)
        {           

            ...
        }
    }
```

Is there a way to instantiate the Startup class with the default constructor parameter from the Program class?
Note: I have updated to show how the StatelessServiceContext is initialized.

With above, I'm getting this error: Unable to resolve service for type 'System.Fabric.StatelessServiceContext' while attempting to activate StartUp
Thanks.

Comment: Why? What are you trying to pass from Program.cs to Startup? In addition, you don't need to use a Startup class. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/50-to-60?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=visual-studio#smhm

Comment: Afaik `Startup` only accepts `IConfiguration`. However for ASP.NET Core you can inject services in the `Configure` method which builds the http pipeline

Comment: StatelessServiceContext is that something from you? Or is it a 3rd Party thing that should have documentation on how to use it within asp.net core?

Comment: @Ralf, StatelessServiceContext is part of Microsoft Service Fabric. The app is deployed on Service Fabric

Comment: How are you initializing `StatelessServiceContext`?

Comment: Then maybe just do what the documentation tells you how that should be done? Like here  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-services-communication-aspnetcore#kestrel-in-a-stateful-service. Register the context in the service collection and then retrieve via DI where ever you want. Startup ctor seems a bad choice but i don't see why the code you show in the ctor needs to be there could be somewhere else.

Comment: @gunr2171, I have edited my original post to reflect how it is initialized

Comment: You just need to add a service to your service collection with a factory and move these 2 lines to the factory method. Like [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection-guidelines#async-di-factories-can-cause-deadlocks) but without the `.Result` ofc

Comment: You could resolve service in startup.cs.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using dependency injection for service in startup. You could try below get a context instance in "ConfigureServices"

```
var _context = services.BuildServiceProvider().GetService<StatelessServiceContext>()
```

Comment: This answer contradicts itself. Not only is it using dependency injection, it's constructing a throwaway service provider just to call a single service. There's no need for this. If `StatelessServiceContext` is already registered, it's available in any factory method